# copied same android project to another folder then prompts errors, why?

Tags: android, inflate

I have a android project that runs fine on the vm, but when I created a new project and exactly the same files inside that project then copied the original code to the files respectively, the project just keeps prompt "unfortunately, *** has stopped". why? and the error message is as follow:

```
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testfra/com.example.testfra.FragTestActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class Fragment
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class Fragment
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at com.example.testfra.FragTestActivity.onCreate(FragTestActivity.java:12)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  ... 11 more
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.Fragment
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:636)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  ... 21 mor
```

e

Comment: actually, in the beginning i wrote my own project (no copy,everything is written manually) followed the logic in the original project, but it prompts error exactly like those errors, something about the inflate thingy. and i spent whole night checking the possible error, no good. so then i thought of copy the codes, still same error.

Comment: i tried 1.clean 2.check no reference to resources outside the package. no good...

Comment: Are you creating any custom view here? If yes then HOW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are using eclipse for your project.

A couple things you could try.  I've found that copying and pasting code fragments into eclipse sometimes causes certain imports to be automatically inserted. Check to make sure that your imports are correct and pointing to the right files.

Other than that try doing a project clean. Click Project -> Clean

Finally if those both don't work, you can try right clicking your file. Select "Android tools", then select "Fix Project Properties".

If all these don't work, make sure that you have included any other dependencies you may be using. (jar files etc..)

Hopefully this helps!

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. do you have any idea what could cause this error "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file"  ?

Comment: Hi Zoey, that error is being called after a series of other errors. If you look down your stack trace, the "classnotfoundException" is at the root of your problem, and that cascades up to the InflateException error. Therefore there could be many possible ways for an inflate exception to be called in general. I bet if you debugged your code in your PhoneLayoutInflater.java file, you would see exactly which line of code it breaks on. (In the onCreate) If it breaks when loading a view the error is likely in the views xml file.

Comment: PhoneLayoutInflater.java file? I didnt create such file.

Comment: Sorry, i typed that out too fast. The PhoneLayoutInflator is an android class file. If you look here http://source-android.frandroid.com/frameworks/base/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneLayoutInflater.java   you can see that it extents LayoutInflator (which instantiates your layout xml file).  This could be caused by an error in one of your xml files. (Sometimes eclipse just doesn't know how to link properly). Try recreating the xml file for Activities view. And if the code was working before just copy and paste it in the new file.

Comment: thank you very much for this detailed explanation! Though i still didnt find the answer, I wrote the code all over again then worked... quite strange, and cant explain why.

Comment: Sometimes these types of issues happen.. But I'm glad you got it working! =)

Answer (score 0):

There can be several reasons for this.

First you must "clean" the build cache and prebuilt binaries before doing something like this.

Second, you need to double check that there are no absolute references to anything that you changed in the transfer (project name, project directory, etc.)

These are you two most likely problems.